# Асинхронная загрузка с прогрессом

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

Разрабатываю программу, с помощью которой можно было бы асинхронно скачивать до трех картинок и смотреть на прогресс (на форме 3 кнопки "скачать" и 3 пикчербокса с прогрессбаром). Из процесса гугления понял, что использование WebClient для таких целей не подходит, зато написали, что подходит HttpClient (полагаю, что создание n штук WebClient-объектов, где n - кол-во файлов, плохая практика).

Заменив в коде тип WebClient на HttpClient, обнаружил, что отсутствуют события, с помощью которых WebClient давал возможность легко отображать прогресс загрузки. Жду ваших идей по поводу того, как можно отображать прогресс загрузки.

P.S. Использовал следующий код для отображения прогресса с WebClient:

```
  wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            MethodInvoker method = () =>
            {
                int percent = e.ProgressPercentage;
                progressBar1.Value = percent;
                label1.Text = $"{percent}/100 %";
            };
            this.Invoke(method);
        };

        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The download is completed!");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        };
```

Comment: Используйте 3 WebClient и не парьтесь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20661652/5045688